# Scrollable TextView within a CardView

Tags: android, scrollbar, android-scrollview, android-cardview

I am trying to implement a TextView to scroll vertically within a CardView if the text is too large to fit.

Unfortunately this code does not work as intended. Could you help me please?

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewBookImage"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewBookName_EN"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="BookName_EN" />


            <ScrollView
                android:id="@+id/textAreaScroller"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="173px"
                android:layout_x="0px"
                android:layout_y="25px"
                android:scrollbars="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewBookDescription"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:lines="7"
                    android:text="Book Description" />
            </ScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: A TextView will become scrollable by itself if its content goes beyond its bounds. Have you tried simply using the TextView without the ScrollView around it?

Comment: Hi NoChinDeluxe. Thanks for your reply. Yes I have and the text, if too long, is not shown within the CardView unfortunately.

Comment: I think that's because you set the `lines` attribute in your TextView to "7". Try removing that line and putting "match_parent" for your TextView `layout_height`.

Comment: Thanks but it is still not working.

Answer (score 0):

In your `Activity` add this line to your `TextView`:

```
TextView tv;
...

tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewBookDescription);
tv .setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```